# How do I update routes from Rails 2 to Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Here are some routes I have in Rails 2 and want to upgrade to Rails 3:

```
  map.callback "/auth/:provider/callback", :controller => "authorizations", :action => "create" #omniauth
  map.failure "/auth/failure", :controller => "authorizations", :action => "failure" #omniauth

  map.signup 'signup', :controller => 'users', :action => 'new'
  map.signin 'signin', :controller => 'user_sessions', :action => 'new'
  map.signout 'signout', :controller => 'user_sessions', :action => 'destroy'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
match "/auth/:provider/callback" => "authorizations#create", :as => :callback
match "/auth/failure" => "authorizations#failure", :as => :failure

match "signup"  => "users#new", :as => :signup
match "signin"  => "user_sessions#new", :as => :signin
match "signout" => "user_sessions#destroy", :as => :signout
```

That should get you going.

I would definitely checkout the screencast that `apneadiving` mentioned as well as [Rails' take on routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the rails_upgrade plugin at https://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade and its `rake rails:upgrade:routes`.

```
script/plugin install git://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade.git
rake rails:upgrade:routes
```

This will take your current routes file and rewrites it using the Rails 3 syntax. Copy the console output and look for any potential optimizations after you've read through the documentation in some of the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

This should answer and make you learn:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/203-routing-in-rails-3

Answer (score 2):

You may also find lots of great information at the [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).